# Escape grouping as macro + feedback

Tags: expansion, latex3, xkeyval

I am currently trying my hand at latex3 to get a deeper understanding of programming with latex. For this I have created a simple settings system.

It works as follows:

1. You create a setting via `\NewSetting[type = <type>, init = <init-value>]{<Name>}`
2. Based on its type it calls its corresponding setting macro: e.g. for a string setting it will call `\NewStringSetting[<init-value>]{<Name>}`.
3. `\NewStringSetting` will create the string, set the initial value of the string and create all needed macros to use the string, e.g. `Clear<Name>`, `Set<Name>` and `Get<Name>`.

**Example |** A string setting for author:

1. I create a setting by calling `\NewSetting[type = string, init = Dave]{Author}`
2. **Internal**: `\NewSetting` calls `\NewStringSetting[Dave]{Author}`
3. **Internal**: `\NewStringSetting` creates an expl3 string (`g_my_author_str`), sets if needed a value and creates 3 macros: `\ClearAuthor`, `\SetAuthor{<Content>}` and `\GetAuthor`.

Now I can clear, set and get the content for the string author.

**Problem**: I use `xkeyval` for key-value pairs. They get set in `\NewSetting` via `\setkeys` within a group so they reset after leaving the group (see [David Carlisle's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/690069/293060)). But then all created macros (`\ClearAuthor`, `\SetAuthor{<Content>}` and `\GetAuthor`) are undefined after leaving the group. A solution would be to get rid of the group but then the key-value pairs wont reset as intended. So not really a solution. Then I stumbled across [@wipet's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/690700/latex3-elegant-way-to-forward-a-variable-outside-of-the-group) to forward the macros out of the group; thus keeping the macros while still all keys reset at the end of the group. Looks like a working solution.

**Question**: I am still quite new to LaTeX, especially latex3. I'm fairly satisfied with the result so far (it works, after all) but I'd like to know what you think. I would like to know if there is an easier way and what I could improve.

The biggest difficulty I had was expansion. Are there any good references (e.g. Youtube, forum posts, etc.)? (especially those that also address latex3 and their primitives like `\exp_last_unbraced` ...)

**Summa summarum**:

1. how could the code be improved (especially with regard to the problem I described)?
2. are there any good references explaining latex3 (I know of LaTeX3's manual)?
3. is there some rule of thumb to get expansion right without trial and error

**Code of string setting**:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{expl3} % Only needed for IDE-autocomplete (aka IntelliSense)
\usepackage{xkeyval}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn

% By egreg https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63233/293060
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\IfNoValueOrEmptyTF}{m m m}{%
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{#2}{%
        \tl_if_empty:nTF{#1}{#2}{#3}%
    }%
}%

% By wipet https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/690710/293060
\def\keepaftergroup#1{%
   \global \expandafter\let \csname x:\string#1\endcsname =#1
   \aftergroup\let
   \aftergroup#1%
   \expandafter\aftergroup \csname x:\string#1\endcsname
   
}

\define@key[DAVE]{settings}{type}{\def\DAVE@Settings@Type{#1}}
\define@key[DAVE]{settings}{init}{\def\DAVE@Settings@Init{#1}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\NewSetting}{o m}{%
    \begingroup
        \setkeys[DAVE]{settings}{#1}%
        \cs_if_exist:NTF\DAVE@Settings@Type{%
            \str_case:NnF{\DAVE@Settings@Type}{%
                {string}{\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\NewStringSetting[\cs_if_exist:NT\DAVE@Settings@Init{\DAVE@Settings@Init}]{#2}}\keepaftergroup\x} % <--- Wont work without \keepaftergroup, only if \begingroup + \endgroup removed (but then keys wont reset)
                %{bool}{...}
            }{%
                \ClassError{SETTINGS}{Unknown~settings~type~for~setting~'#2'}{}
            }
        }{%
            \ClassError{SETTINGS}{Cannot~create~setting~'#2'~due~to~missing~setting~type}{}
        }
    \endgroup
    \x % <--- Calling
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\NewStringSetting}{o m}{%
    \str_if_exist:cTF{g_DAVE_#2_str}{%
        \ClassError{SETTINGS}{String~with~the~name~'#2'~already~exist}{}
    }{%
        \str_gclear_new:c{g_DAVE_#2_str}
        \IfValueT{#1}{%
            \str_gset:cn{g_DAVE_#2_str}{#1}
        }
        \expandafter\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\expandafter{\csname Clear#2\endcsname}{}{%
            \str_gclear:c{g_DAVE_#1_str}
        }
        \expandafter\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\expandafter{\csname Set#2\endcsname}{m}{%
            \IfNoValueOrEmptyTF{##1}{%
                \ClassWarning{SETTINGS}{Could~not~set~value~for~setting~'#2'~due~to~the~passed~value~being~of~type~'NoValue'~or~empty}%
            }{%
                \str_gset:cn{g_DAVE_#2_str}{##1}%
            }%
        }
        \expandafter\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\expandafter{\csname Get#2\endcsname}{}{%
            \str_use:c{g_DAVE_#2_str}
        }
    }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\NewSetting[type = string]{Forum}
\NewSetting[type = string, init = Dave]{Author}

\SetForum{StackExchange}

\begin{document}
    Hello \TeX-\GetForum \space it's \GetAuthor
\end{document}
```

Comment: don't use xkeyval here if your aim is to use L3 use l3keys which is anyway preloaded in latex so requires no package

Comment: also don't reset after a group with macros that have been set globally, as here.  as the initial setting applies to all nested group levels but the reset is a local setting for just one level, which is well defined but weird.